# how to import gimp in python3 script?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, gimp

Sorry for a noob question, but I can't seem to find gimp's install command.

> $ pip3 install pgimp

throws the below error

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tt98fv7k/pgimp/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tt98fv7k/pgimp/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tt98fv7k/pgimp/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tt98fv7k/pgimp/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        check_python2_installation()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tt98fv7k/pgimp/setup.py", line 38, in check_python2_installation
        'At least one of the following packages is missing in the python2 installation: ' + ', '.join(requirements)
    __main__.GimpInstallationException: At least one of the following packages is missing in the python2 installation: numpy, typing
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `At least one of the following packages is missing in the python2 installation: numpy, typing` install these

Comment: Also, check the **Installation** section of [pgimp PyPi package](https://pypi.org/project/pgimp/): "_As gimp uses a python2 interpreter, the pip packages numpy and typing for python2 need to be installed._". Note that you seem to be using Python 3 (`pip3`) but you need to install them on Python 2.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: It's useful to add the GIMP version - the comments are correct for version up to 2.10, but when people read "python3" and "gimp", they might assume that you are trying this with the current GIMP development branch.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is possible to add Gimp into python, but if you have installed [gimp beta with flatpack](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/devel/) (I tried it on Ubuntu and OpenSuse) you can run a interactive bash or python shell in witch you can find gimp:

```
flatpak run --command=python org.gimp.GIMP//beta
```

In this way it open a python shell that can import gimp like into a plugin.

If you want to run a script you can use a bash shell inside it you can run for example `python -m ensurepip` and start to install with pip your dependencies:

```
flatpak run --command=bash org.gimp.GIMP//beta
```

I find more information about that on [Create Python3 Plugin for GIMP: The basics](https://z-uo.medium.com/create-python3-plugin-for-gimp-the-basics-94ede94e9d1f) and on [Some ideas and tools to develop Python 3.8 plugins for GIMP 2.99.4](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/isman7-gimp-python-development)